# Using a For Loop to Change Image Properties in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop

I've got a set of IBOutlets that I've created with names card0, card1 ... card10, card11.

I want to hide them all. I can simply use this code:

```
card0.hidden = false
card1.hidden = false
card2.hidden = false
card3.hidden = false
card4.hidden = false
card5.hidden = false
card6.hidden = false
card7.hidden = false
card8.hidden = false
card9.hidden = false
card10.hidden = false
card11.hidden = false
```

While it works, I'd like to create a For Loop that saves me some trouble and makes my code look prettier. Here's as far as I've gotten:

```
var cardName = [card0, card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6, card7, card8, card9, card10, card11]

for var i = 0; i<12; i++ {
cardName[i].hidden = false
}
```

I'm getting an error that AnyObject does not have a member named "hidden."

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Hey John, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list must have been initialised as a `[AnyObject]` not a `[NSView]` (Or whatever your IBOutlets point to).

You should be able to explicitly say that it should be a `[NSView]`:

```
let cards: [NSView] = [ /* Cards */ ]
```

(Note that the `let` keyword should be used here as the list isn't going to mutate)

You could also cast the object in the loop, but this would be messier:

```
for var i = 0; i<12; i++ {
    (cardName[i] as NSView).hidden = false
}
```

Oh! and you can do loops like this in Swift too!

```
for card in cardName {
    card.hidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you alt-click on your `cardName` variable, you will see that it is of type `[AnyObject!]`, and `AnyObject` does not have a property `hidden`. You need to specify the type of your outlets so that the constructed array will infer the correct type (and the compiler will recognise the `hidden` property on that type):

```
@IBOutlet weak var card0: UIView!    // (or whatever specific UIView subclass it is)
@IBOutlet weak var card1: UIView!
// ...
```

Also, it really looks like these ought to be declared as an outlet *collection*, rather than individual outlets. An outlet collection simple specifies an *array* of views, and will greatly simplify your code:

```
@IBOutlet var cards: [UIView]!
```

Hook them up like you would a regular `@IBOutlet`, but specify the same outlet collection "`cards`" for each card. They will then be collected into an array in code, so to hide all the cards it's simply:

```
for card in cards {
    card.hidden = true
}
```